How can I construct a variable in JavaScript based on another variables value? And How can I reassign it's value and perform methods on that variable?
I want to be able to basically do this
let x = 1;
let `arr${x}`;

if ((i = 0)) `arr${x}` = [];
`arr${x}`.push(words);
console.log(`arr${x}`);

I have tried using eval()
let x = 1;
eval(`let arr${x}`);

if ((i = 0)) eval(`arr${x} = [];`);
eval(`arr${x}.push(${words})`);
console.log(eval(`arr${x}`));

But it's giving an error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: arr1 is not defined
In this line: eval(arr${x}.push(${words}));

eval is the only way, JS doesn't have a concept of dynamically created variable names. I'd suggest you to use a suitable data structure instead (ex. object). Notice, that i = 0 in the conditions doesn't do what you think it does.

Why not just use a list?

@Teemu Here is a link to codepen for the whole code, so you would understand better of what I'm trying to do:
https://codepen.io/huz3y/pen/yLWNedW

Why not add that code right in the question, instead of linking it, as a Stack snippet?

You can't do this with variables, but you can very well do it with object properties. If the object you create it on happens to be the global object (window in browsers) this will also create a global variable:


let x = 1, words = "some words here", i = 0;
window[`arr${x}`] = undefined;

if (i===0) window[`arr${x}`] = [];
window[`arr${x}`].push(words);
console.log(window[`arr${x}`]);
console.log(arr1);




This was what I was looking for!! You managed to answer me eventhough I gave very little context. Thanks
